# Wrong numbering of lines in lstlistings when using escaped commands

Tags: listings, line-numbering

I'm using the listings package to format some Java code in my document.

I want it to number lines (1 number every 5 lines), and I need to highlight some keywords inside the code with the following command:

```
\newcommand{\ca}[1]{\color{red}{#1}}
```

(escaped with "`" inside the lstlisting environment).

However, if I use this command on any line, the next line will be numbered, regardless of its number.

Here is a simplified example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{
  language=Java,
  numbers=left,
  stepnumber=5,
  numberfirstline=true,
  numbersep=5pt,
  escapechar=\`
}

\newcommand{\ca}[1]{\color{red}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
public class Color {
  private int R, G, B;
  public `\ca{final static}` Color red = `\ca{new}` Color(255, 0, 0);
  public `\ca{final static}` Color magenta = `\ca{new}` Color(255, 0, 255);
  public `\ca{final static}` Color lightgray = `\ca{new}` Color(192, 192, 192);
  // ...
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

(in my real document it's much more complex: Beamer, TikZ, etc.)

Here is the result I get: [image: incorrect numbering]
Lines 4 and 5 should not be numbered, and if I just remove the "`" they *are not* numbered.

Any idea how to fix this? Did I do something wrong, or is it a bug in listings?

Comment: Found a workaround: disable "numberfirstline". Not perfect (I'd like the first line to be numbered...), but better than nothing. Leaving the question open in case anyone has a real fix :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{
  language=Java,
  numbers=left,
  stepnumber=5,
  numberfirstline=true,
  numbersep=5pt,
  escapechar=\`
}

\makeatletter% ADDED
\newcommand{\ca}[1]{\color{red}{#1}%
  \aftergroup\lst@numberfirstlinefalse% ADDED
}
\makeatother% ADDED

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
public class Color {
  private int R, G, B;
  public `\ca{final static}` Color red = `\ca{new}` Color(255, 0, 0);
  public `\ca{final static}` Color magenta = `\ca{new}` Color(255, 0, 255);
  public `\ca{final static}` Color lightgray = `\ca{new}` Color(192, 192, 192);
  // ...
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a different method that avoids escaping to TeX code and is adaptable to different situations without marking up the original code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{
  language=Java,
  numbers=left,
  stepnumber=5,
  numberfirstline=true,
  numbersep=5pt,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[emph={[2]final,static,new},emphstyle={[2]\color{red}}]
public class Color {
  private int R, G, B;
  public final static Color red = new Color(255, 0, 0);
  public final static Color magenta = new Color(255, 0, 255);
  public final static Color lightgray = new Color(192, 192, 192);
  // ...
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, obviously. But in other parts of the document I want to highlight different things, not necessarily keywords (sometimes an int value, sometimes Javadoc), so using `emph` would be quite troublesome. Thanks for the suggestion though.